# Use a slack command as a shortcut for multiple commands

Tags: slack-api

My company has recently switched to Slack, and I'm really enjoying it so far. I'm learning about Slack Custom commands, and I would like to try writing a few.

One of the first ideas I had was to create a shortcut for going away -- either for lunch, or for a short break. When I go to lunch, I set my status as "Away" with the `/away` command, and snooze notifications with `/dnd 1 hour`. It would be nice if I could create a custom Slack command, called `/lunch` that does both of these things, and another one called `/back` that switches back to Online and not Snoozed.

All of the documentation for Custom Commands is oriented towards interfacing with an external API, but is there a way to write a custom command that triggers actions within Slack itself? Would this require using the Slack API?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you would have to use the Slack API. But that's fine, because it's really fun to use :)

You can programmatically set your `away` preference with this method:
https://api.slack.com/methods/users.setPresence

And you can set your `do not disturb` duration with this one:
https://api.slack.com/methods/dnd.setSnooze

The guide for getting started with a custom integration is [here.](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Great! I was hoping this might work. So then I assume that this will automatically set those values for the currently authenticated user? Also, is it possible to have it echo a command/message back to the screen? I.e., something like `/me is taking a break`?

Comment: It is definitely possible to echo back a message. This is the easy part. In terms of dealing with it on a per user basis, this might be more difficult if you require explicit OAuth scopes. Check https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes for whether you do.

Comment: If I understand this response correctly, then there is no easy way to set up a macro or batch of commands?  For example, when creating a new channel, I currently (manually) run a series of /poll commands to create and pin a number of polls to the new channel.  It's a bit of tedious copy/pasting, followed by some tedious UI selection and confirmation.  If I could copy/paste the whole set of commands (or a macro/script/alias/batch) in a single action, it would make the process much cleaner and easier.  So, do you know if this is possible or not?  I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: @Pseudothink this is not possible with Slack's API, as slash commands (such as /poll) need to be invoked by the user. But with Selenium, anything is possible ;)